# two linear layouts but only one displays

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

My parent layout is a linear layout and inside I am trying to add two linear layouts.  For some reason. The only layout that will show is the linear layout with the two buttons and the other never appears....any suggestions?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_actionsText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:text="Text"/>
    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_actionsSpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button android:id="@+id/dynamic_btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/dynamic_btnSave"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: provide full XML........

Comment: well on the first layout you have "TextVIew" instead of "TextView"

Comment: I found that error at run time and changed it in my real code I just forgot to on this.

Comment: well to me your code works fine. Altough I changed the visibility of the buttons and the width of them from 0 to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the visibility as gone (as mentioned by Dheeresh)

Now, the button 's android:layout_height="wrap_content" is the problem.

Since the buttons have no text content in them their height is essentially = 0 (wrap_content 's behavior)

Add an attribute as android:text="Hi" in both the buttons. you should be able to see them now.

If you intend to do the entire operation dynamically then do as follows,

```
Button btnSubmit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_btnSubmit);
btnSubmit.setText("Submit");
Button btnSave=(Button) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_btnSave);
btnSave.setText("Save");
btnSubmit.setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE);
btnSave.setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: however he mentions that the one that is actually visible is the one with the buttons so assuming that the "wrap_content" attribute is the one wrong then he had to be putting a background on code for the buttons that be taking most part of the screen. But even if that was the case, the weight attribute would stop this to happen. isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

```
any suggestions?
```

suggestions:

1 - Set the orientation vertical to **parent of both LinearLayout** .....

2-  remove android:visibility="gone" from dynamic_btnSubmit  and  dynamic_btnSave

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_actionsText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Text" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_actionsSpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_btnSave"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I attempted these changes but am still left with only one linear layout.